# I am getting error while running with this @bean

Tags: java, javabeans

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localeResolver' defined in com.restservices.NewSpringbootbuildingblocksApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver]: Factory method 'localeResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
```

My code is running when I commented below mentioned code

```
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
            AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
            localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
            return localeResolver();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are calling your `localeResolver()` method in your return statement. Try changing your return statement to `return localeResolver`

Answer (score 0):

You can review your error again. It is throwing below exception.

```
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Check your code again you are calling method recursively.

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return localeResolver(); <-- Calling same method again.
}
```

I think you want to return localeResolver variable instead of calling same method again.